# Cannot access website on EC2 web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 free web server, running IIS I cannot access externally.

1. I see the IIS default page locally, so I know that IIS is running fine
2. I have added port 80 and 0.0.0.0/0 to the security group (both inbound and outbound).
3. As a quick test, I completely (temporarily) turned off the firewall in Windows and still couldn't get to the page.

Is there anything else I should be looking at?

Thanks!

Comment: Troubleshoot an Unreachable (Windows) Instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/screenshot-service.html

Comment: Try accessing from a different network (eg home vs work) to make sure there's nothing blocking you. Verify that the Public IP address is correct (hasn't changed). From the instance itself, try accessing the instance's public IP address.

Comment: Can't access the public IP from the instance itself.